# Round to even (or uneven) multiples of some basic float unit

Tags: java, rounding

How do I round to even multiples of some basic float unit (say `0.0005f`)

```
float example_input = 2.718281828459f;

float unit = 0.0005f;
```

such that the `output` is of the form `2*n*unit`, with `n` being a natural number, and `output` being as close as possible to `example_input`

Also, how is this done for uneven multiples?

edit: this is what I've come up with so far, but it's wrong:

```
float roundToEvenMultiple(float input, float unit){
    float output = input - (input % (2*unit));
    return output;
}

float roundToUnevenMultiple(float input, float unit){
    float output = input - (input % (3*unit));
    return output;
}
```

edit 2:

This is another stab at the problem, but will not work for negative numbers, and seems very inefficient.

```
  float roundToEvenMultiple(float input, float unit){

    float result = 0;
    while (result < input){
      result += 2*unit;
    }
    return result;
  }

  float roundToUnevenMultiple(float input, float unit){

    float result = 0;
    while (result < input){
      result += 3*unit;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

edit 3:

for the

```
example_input = 2.718281828459f;
```

and

```
unit = 0.0005f;
```

the even multiple rounding procedure should output: `2.718`
the uneven multiple rounding procedure should output: `2.7185`

Comment: The language you're using probably has some sort of `round()` function/method. You haven't specified which language that is, though.

Comment: java in my case

Comment: but Math round in java won't let me specify to round to even multiples of some basic unit, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to use the truncated value in calculations, or just display it to the user with fewer decimal places? If the latter, consider `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: I need to use it in calculations

Comment: Please, add a [mcve] with complete input/output. This isn't really clear in my head. Also, you should show what you have tried, to let us know you have do something more than posting the question here (which is required based on SO rules).

Comment: I can show what I tried, but it's wrong and I don't have a clear idea of how to express it in code.. The mathematics that need to hold are described in the original post. (output is of the form 2*n*unit, with n being a natural number)

Comment: What is wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But this still lack some example with some input/output expected like asked in a [mcve]

Comment: What about when the input number is exactly half way between two possible outputs? e.g. example_input = 0.125, unit = 0.05; do you want output = 0.10 or output = 0.15?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException rounding up is acceptable for my purposes

Comment: @AxelH I've provided some example output, now, and also another naive procedure, to illustrate what I'm trying to do

Comment: The uneven multiples procedure is wrong. You don't want to round to 3*n*unit; you want to round to (2*n+1)*unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let k be the number of units in the input x.
Then if k is odd, the rest is less than a unit, so k*unit is the result.
If k is even, the number is in the upper half of the odd k-1, so (k+1)*unit is the result.

```
float roundToUnevenMultiple(float x, float unit) {
    int k = (int) (x / unit);
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        ++k; // Upper half
    }
    return k * unit;
}
```

The even multiple case was already simple. But could be done alike:

```
float roundToEvenMultiple(float x, float unit) {
    int k = (int) (x / unit);
    if (k % 2 == 1) {
        ++k; // Upper half
    }
    return k * unit;
}
```

With large k the approximation error in the unit will be enlarged. So it would be more precise to do:

```
float roundToUnevenMultiple(float x, float unit) {
    float remainder = x % unit;
    float y = x - remainder;
    int k = (int) (x / unit);
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        y += unit;
    }
    return y;
}

float roundToEvenMultiple(float x, float unit) {
    float remainder = x % unit;
    float y = x - remainder;
    int k = (int) (x / unit);
    if (k % 2 == 1) {
        y += unit;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Using `double` would certainly be better, more common, main practice.

Comment: This works! Thanks! I wouldn't have come up with a solution in a million years!

Comment: use double because of higher precision?

Comment: Yes, the sole area of application of `float` is for GUI coordinates, 2D, fonts.

Comment: My main reason for using `float`, had so far been, that I had the vague idea that it is more performant than `double` precision. I guess I could test this to know for sure.

Comment: It is 16 significant digits for double against 7 for float. So with your example data it was not entirely unproblematic. However float is faster, ideal for font rendering and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(round(2.718281828459f, 0.00002f));
}

static float round(float num, float granularity) {
  return Math.round(num * (1.0f/granularity)) * granularity)
}
```

The output is `2.71828`.

Do consider, though, that if you're truncating a value before using it in a calculation then it's subject to cumulative error. You'll have better results if you retain its original precision and then use [`System.out.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to display it to the user.

Comment: Why are you using floats? Why do you divide by 1/granularity instead of just multiplying? Likewise, why don't you just divide num instead of dividing and multiplying? Also, do you think this does anything different than what op is doing with their `%` operator?

Comment: @matt I'm using floats because that's what OP was using. Point taken about multiplying by granularity though.

Comment: It's not for display. The situation is: I have two sets of numbers (floats)  (set A and set B). I want to round each number from both sets to be a multiple of 0.0005. But the results from set A should never be equal to the results of set B. That's why I need to round one set to even and the other to uneven multiples